# How to get Facebook comments count with HTML5?

Tags: facebook, html

I know two ways to retrieve the number of comments on Facebook:

```
<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count> awesome comments
```

and...

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=example.com&permalink=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

But none is a semantics for HTML5 solution, is there any alternative?

Comment: the only way you can grab data from facebook is by, well, grabbing data from facebook. you'll need to use one of their API's to do so, whether that's javascript, php, ruby, python, etc...

Comment: Thanks Connor, but fb:comments-count is a plugin. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since **[v2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments)**, it can be handled by `span`, which already has the natively `display: inline;` semantics.

```
<a href="/post-link">
  <span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="/post-link">0</span> comments
</a>
```

Answer (score 33):

You can also get HTML5 valid FB comment count this way:

```
<div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="/post URL">0</div>
```

FB automatically replaces the "0" with the correct number. If you put something there like "awesome comments", it will be replaced with the number of comments i.e. "13", etc.

In order to get the number and use your own text, do something like this:

```
<a href="/post URL"><div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="/post URL">0</div> awesome comments</a>
```

Notice you must wrap your class in div's or else the comment counter will not work.

Answer (score 13):

Graph API example using jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.google.com',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
             alert("comments: " + data.comments);
       }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: This is must be on the top.

Answer (score -1):

For an wordpress post u can use like `<fb:comments-count href=<?php the_permalink();?>></fb:comments-count> awesome comments`