# Facebook comments count clickable

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments

I'm using a facebook plugin on my wordpress site. I put the code below on the loop and single.php page to show the number of comments

```
<fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count> Comments
```

it displays  the number of comments but it's not clickable like a normal WP count.. how can I make it clickable so it will link to the permalink?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
<a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
<div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">0</div>
comments</a>
```

Note the < div > block

You may also want to add one of these sharing libraries temporarily and then inspect the elements and view the javascript to see exactly how they are doing it.

https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing

http://sharethis.com

See also

[How to get Facebook comments count with HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642631/how-to-get-facebook-comments-count-with-html5)

[<fb:comments-count> not working on my WordPress powered blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956488/fbcomments-count-not-working-on-my-wordpress-powered-blog?rq=1)

[How to get Facebook comments count with HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642631/how-to-get-facebook-comments-count-with-html5)